# Synch Openlayers with Datagrid - Example/Snippet?

Tags: datagrid, openlayers

The datagrid not yet selected, but it will be one available with any of the more popular JS libraries.

Example of such integration might be if a row is hidden then its corresponding marker feature also is, as a result of the same user action.

URL's pointing to online examples highly appreciated, and/or JS code snippet to accomplish such.  Thanks, all.

Answer (score 1):

See this GeoExt example for integration with ExtJs: http://api.geoext.org/1.0/examples/feature-grid.html